# How to clear all browser cache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, https, http-headers, browser-cache

I have set "Cache-Control: max-age:99999999999999" from web.config file

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
       <add name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=99999999999999" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This set max-age to all file ajax requests also :( Because of this old contents were keep showing on the browser.

It's too late, so many users visited the site, all contents were showing from the old cache file.

Then I have set "Cache-Control: no-cache", it only clears the cache only for the landing page. Ajax requests still showing old data.

Is there a way I can delete all cached files received from the server?

Is there any javascript code or any command HTTP command I can use?

Comment: You can attach a dummy parameter after your AJAX request URL thru JS. e.g. '&_d=' + new Date().

Comment: we have so many pages, and so many ajax requests, I cannot change all of them one by one :(

Comment: Create an interceptor for all request. http://www.diwebsity.com/2015/11/26/intercept-http-requests-ajaxjquery/

Comment: I've found that

`$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

force not to use browser cache, but also it won't clear the browser cache. (If I comment the code then it's again using the browser cache).

Comment: Usually, in this case, I would really recommend to refactor the code even it is cost a lot. That gives you more flexibility and extensibility.